# Strategies for solving overfitting - other options?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, categorical-data

I am building a predictive model where I want to know can I predict whether a package will be delivered on time (Binary Yes / No), in the event that the package is not delivered on time, I wish to be able to predict by when it will be delivered in categories of <7days, <14days, <21days >28days after expected date.

I have built and tested a model for binary classification and have got an f Score of 0.92, which is satisfactory for my needs.  However, when I train my categorical model, I start to see training accuracy and validation accuracy diverge (training accuracy is much better than validation accuracy).  This is a sign of overfitting.

However, I have tried regularization and different values, plus using dropout and different values, and the validation accuracy never gets above 0.7. My total training set is of ~10k examples, ~3k validation, and whilst the catgorical spread is not equal there are sufficient examples of each category (I think). I am using a NN and have increased / decreased both layers and activations and still no joy

Any thoughts on where to go next. Thanks

Comment: you say the categorical spread is unequal - how unequal are we talking? how many samples do you have per category (approx.)?

Comment: What are your explanatory variables? Perhaps also worth checking, why aren't you using parametric methods? Not that you should but just wondering what the data is like.

Comment: @Tagas: I have varied the ranges of the categories to see if could get any increase in performance. So in one instance, I had Cat1: ~4k samples, Cat2: ~2k, Cat3: ~2k, Cat4: ~1k.  Test set reflected the same level of proportionality. I had played around with the categories some being a week, some being 2 weeks, but always tried to get the same proportions in both sets

Comment: @Neil: I have 24 features, consisting of date time of order, city, location etc.  If that is what you mean by explanatory variables.  I have not considered parametric methods, I will talk to one of the stats people and see what they can come up with

Comment: @1961DarthVader Ok that doesn't seem too bad... maybe you could still try to resample your data and just use let's say ~1k samples for each category, just to see what happens. See also https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Comment: @Tagas, this looks a very interesting page.  Let me try it and see where we end up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using NN, introduce dropout layers. See if it can help to reduce the overfitting problem. And also checkout this [How to choose the number of hidden layers and nodes in a feedforward neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw)

The more complex the network (hidden layers, number of neurons in them), also contribute to overfitting problem

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have tried applying the rules of thumb as mentioned in these links.  On the one hand it simplified my model greatly, but unfortunately, it also allowed me to see the divergence very, very quickly.  I have tried the dropout layers as well but also to no avail.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Then another thing i can think of is playing around with learning rate, start with small steps

Comment: Xitrum, Thanks for that but unfortunately that has also not improved the result, the accuracies diverge when the validation accuracy reaches ~0.68 - 0.7.  We had a call this morning and are looking at some feature boosting techniques and to create a relevant, yet different target variable - I know that normally addresses bias, but our thinking is to try looking at different techniques if this is not working as we need it to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The approach we have chosen is to carry out a linear regression with the expected duration as target variable.  We have excluded some outliers, and then taken the differences between the actual and predicted days.  We then max'd and min'd the difference and we now have a prediction with a tolerable range.  We will keep working on the other techniques to see if we can improve. Thanks to everyone who suggested ideas